# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS no sound on LG Gram 2021 (a lot of troubleshooting attempted)

Tags: linux, audio

I got a new LG Gram laptop (see specs -> [1](https://www.lg.com/us/laptops/lg-16z90p-k.aas8u1-ultra-slim-laptop)) and immediately replaced windows with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I had no issues with installation other than I have no sound. I am aware of many threads discussing this and I have been troubleshooting for hours. Nothing thus far has worked for me hence why I am asking this question to a community. I will provide as much information as I can regarding what "solutions" I have already tried. Hopefully, someone can help me.

### Solution 1

Firstly I ran through the troubleshooting steps built into Ubuntu's help application:

1. Checked in system settings that sound was not muted
2. Check the correct sound device was connected (I only had the option "Speaker-sof-hda-dsp")
3. Executed `lspci -v` which returned the following output relevant to audio:

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device a0c8 (rev 20)
    Subsystem: LG Electronics, Inc. Device 0400
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 166
    Memory at 603d188000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 603d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
```

I noticed hear that the Kernel driver in use could potentially be set to `snd_hda_intel` so investigated this.

### Solution 2

1. I tried to reinstall `pulseaudio` and `alsa` to no avail, `sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio` & `sudo alsa force-reload`.
2. I checked in `alsamixer` that nothing was muted and tried playing around with manually changing the system sound card but still no sound.

[image]

### Solution 3

I opened `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and changed:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
```

After this I executed `sudo update-grub` and rebooted my system. I could confirm the driver was changed using `aplay -l` but I still had no sound. I gathered more information using `modinfo snd_hda_intel`:

```
parm:           dmic_detect:Allow DSP driver selection (bypass this driver) (0=off, 1=on) (default=1); deprecated, use snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver option instead (bool)
```

Also `modinfo snd_intel_dspcfg` provided:

```
parm:           dsp_driver:Force the DSP driver for Intel DSP (0=auto, 1=legacy, 2=SST, 3=SOF) (int)
```

Following another thread I also added `snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` continuing to update grub and reboot. Still nothing.

### Solution 4

First I reset the solution 3, then I performed the following:

1. Added `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` to `etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`.
2. Added `blacklist snd_soc_skl` to `etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.
3. Reboot

Still no luck. So I have undone these changes for now.

### Further Information

```
User:~$ inxi -SMA
System:    Host: Ryan-Ubuntu-Laptop Kernel: 5.8.0-43-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LG product: 16Z90P-K.AA78A1 v: 0.1 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: LG model: 16Z90P v: FAB1 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: Phoenix v: T2ZF0250 X64 
           date: 01/04/2021 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: sof-audio-pci 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-43-generic
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated as I want to get the system up and running to work on.

Comment: The hardware may be too new and Ubuntu has no driver for it yet.

Comment: I understand this but I thought forcing the system to use the intel driver that was present would work, as least thats the impression I got from many threads on this topic. There must be something I can do, I can't just wait for them to release a driver for me to get any sound on my PC.

Comment: @Moad two years later, same problem. I just bought a 2023 17Z90R, and sound doesn't work on Kubuntu 22, or Fedora 37 or 38.

Answer (score 4):

same here with 2021 lg gram 17Z90P

sound works with headphone jack.

sound works with hdmi port and the two thunderbolt 4 port.

sound works through bluetooth.

But no sound on the laptops own speaker.

on both kubuntu 20.10 and arch linux

Comment: Same here with a 2023 17Z90R. Sund doesn't work on Kubuntu 22, or Fedora 37 or 38.

Answer (score 3):

This bug has been reported to Linux kernel issue tracker.

See [Bug 212041 - LG Gram (2021 Tiger Lake) No sound internel speaker](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212041) and [[BUG] LG Gram laptop (2021 Tiger Lake) Internal speaker no sound #2777](https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/2777).

Here are some replies:

[plbossart](https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/2777#issuecomment-790025542):

> then this is indeed a Linux codec driver issue. Something is missing in the configuration of the HDaudio codec to enable speakers.

[plbossart](https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/2777#issuecomment-790103557):

> it could be easy or complicated to fix this
> a) it's a simple configuration that's missing and can be fixed by a quirk (there are hundreds in ALSA so chances are there are similar devices with the same quirk)
> b) it's more complicated if there are I2S amplifiers connected behind the HDaudio codec, in this case the sequence to program those amplifiers needs to be reverse-engineered. This is what happens on a number of Lenovo devices.

[Takashi Iwai](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212041#c1):

> It's rather the lack of amp initialization, and it's pretty much vendor-specific.  You have to figure out it by yourself via trial-and-error (or try asking the vendor).
> At first, I'd try different model option values.

Answer (score 3):

I have an LG Gram 16 2021 model that had the same problem but now sound on the internal speakers is working! I have the system dual booted. I was using windows side and updating it. Then I got a notification to update LG Bios. After doing this, I lost the ability to boot to ubuntu. So I booted off the live Ubuntu usb, picked the "try it" option, installed grub repair. Ran grub repair which said it had some error. Ignored the error. I then shutdown from the live usb ubuntu, removed the usb drive, then started up the system. Grub reappeared, so I picked the uefi option to check the Uefi setting but made no changes then booted into ubuntu. Sound then worked! I shut down completely. Rebooted, it still worked!!

I suspect it was the BIOS update but just wanted to capture all my steps in case it wasn't.
I hope this helps others with LG gram 2021s.

In response to Ryans question, I looked further into the update. LG update center installed an Intel chip update. It did not provide a URL for the update but I found the matching number here.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/search.html?ws=text#q=10.1.18460.8229&t=Downloads&layout=table

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, would you by any chance know where I can find a BIOS update that I can flash directly via USB. I have not dual booted my LG gram 16 2021 so it is purely running Ubuntu 20.04. Correct me if I am wrong but you were able to update the BIOS via Windows and the LG Software Center? I have looked directly on their website and they do not list anything but the software centre for updating firmware - https://www.lg.com/uk/support/product/lg-16Z90P-K

Comment: Sorry I just saw this note. I believe the update you want may be here.  The LG Update Center software most recently installed this I believe from the windows side. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/search.html?ws=text#q=10.1.18460.8229&t=Downloads&layout=table

Comment: @RyanMaguire: You'd think nearly 2 years later, this BIOS update would ship with newer models. But I just bought a 2023 LG gram 17Z90R, and sound doesn't work on Kubuntu 22, or Fedora 37 or 38.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the bios update worked on my 17Z90P.  I now have sound and for bonus my system runs cooler. Had to do it through windows.

Comment: Two years later, laptops should ship with that update right? I've just bought a 2023 17Z90R, and sound doesn't work on Kubuntu 22, or Fedora 37 or 38.

Comment: @DanDascalescu HI Dan, I just bought an LG 2023 model and I have the same problem. Did you find a solution to make Internal Speakers work?

Answer (score 0):

On archLinux I install sof-firmware and my sound starts working again.
I also have the vulkan-intel , pulseaudio packages installed but as soon as I install sof-firmware my sound is back.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Any idea what I should install on Fedora? `alsa-sof-firmware` is already installed but sound doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Some more info here can be found in Sound Open Firmware issues - though please note it's not a solution for this question - just a mere pointing to a direction which might lead to a solution: https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/4363

It seems like a frequent problem with laptops using a Realtek ALC298 chipset (which includes various LG Gram laptops).

The conclusion was that "it is not well handled in the Linux HDaudio case, be it with the legacy snd-hda-intel or the SOF driver". And solution might be to "Reverse-engineer the Windows audio driver", as described here https://thesofproject.github.io/latest/getting_started/intel_debug/suggestions.html (not an easy feat, but might be possible for the patient!).

> The HDaudio driver configures the codec with ‘verb’ commands to e.g.
> setup the ‘pins’ or a coefficient. The exact values used are
> device-specific, and in the absence of any documentation from the
> codec vendor need to be reverse-engineered by snooping HDAudio
> commands in a Windows environment.

> The following links provide additional information on snooping the
> commands and determining what needs to be added to the Linux kernel.
> These links are not maintained by SOF developers.

> https://asus-linux.org/blog/sound-2021-01-11/

> https://github.com/ryanprescott/realtek-verb-tools/wiki/How-to-sniff-verbs-from-a-Windows-sound-driver

Comment: Please provide more information here. The answers are expected to be complete with references if required

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.